# How to restore alfresco installation

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I previously Backed up folder. Here is how I did.

1. Stopped tomcat and postgres
2. Copied C:/Alfresco to another machine in lan

I then uninstalled Alfresco. Installed new alfresco and deleted the `C:/alfresco` folder and copied the old alfresco folder to it.

Now when I start I am unable to see any contents in share. I am able to see the share header alone. The repository is empty (not even data dictionary or other default folder is visible)

How to restore these ? Is the backup procedure correct. If not what is the correct way to backup? So I can restore in future?

I am using Alfresco 4.2e and default installation

Comment: Did you backup the database as well? Alfresco stores large content objects in the `dir.root` location (typically on windows `c:\alfresco`), but everything else goes into the database (PostGreSQL by default)

Comment: @Gagravarr how to backup the database? I just copied the entire installation directory

Comment: Assuming you're running the default database that the Alfresco Installer provides, you'll be using PostGreSQL. As such, you need to use the [pg_dump utility](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-pgdump.html) to backup your Alfresco database, then the regular `pgsql` command to restore it later. See the [pg_dump manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-pgdump.html) for more on the options, or google for tutorials (there are lots!)

Comment: @Gagravarr as for now I wont be able to restore the old datas??

Comment: If you deleted the previous PostGreSQL instance before backing it up, nope, you'll be out of luck as you deleted most of the Alfresco data in the process. From the [Alfresco Backup and Restore documentation](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Backup_and_Restore#Overview) `Backing up an Alfresco repository involves backing up the directory pointed to by the dir.root setting AND the database Alfresco is configured to use`

Comment: Before backing up, I stopped tomcat and postgre service and then copied the entire folder. I didnt delete anything and compared the size of original installation folder with the copied folder. The size was same

Answer (score 1):

There are mainly 2 places where alfresco is storing data,Both of them are as below.

1. alf_data

   Database

> **alf_data**
>   Here all the files are stored.
>
> **database**
>   Metadata of any content are stored in database.For example properties like modified date,created date,name of document etc...

For restoring alfresco both of them should be in proper place with proper data.Location of **alf_data** is defined in `tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco-global.properties` as well as database information.

Answer (score 0):

which version are your talking about? It should be possile to restore.

Assuming you used the Alfresco installer and your prosgres data is stored in alf_data\postgresql you should be able to restore everything from alf_data (C:\Alfresco\alf_data). So try to uninstall from the new machine and install again, stop alfresco/database and replace the content of alf_data. This is not the standard and recommended backup procedure but should work if you use the same version on both sides and if you really stopped the database before backup.
Unfotunately there is no generic/easy to use B&R tool in the Alfresco install. You need to write you own scripts or you use best practice scripts from others.

Comment: I am using alfresco 4.2 e and default installation, but I am not able to restore

Answer (score 0):

1: check if data exists in alfresco/alf_data

### 2: start postgres, check for data in alfresco database

if all is ok you should be able to retrieve the data, as it is there

---

Check if alfresco is connecting to right repo and right database server.

This should be enough to get data back!

Answer (score 0):

Look [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842070/alfresco-migrating-server/30569657#30569657)

Basics are:

- dump & restore DB
- copy & paste content-stores
- make re-index on new machine

Btw if you'r gonna to another Alfresco version it may not be possible straight way, but usually it'S possible migrate just for 1 version up (eg. 5.0c to 5.0d is ok, but 4.2f for 5.0d makes problems)